# How to remove " " in filename only but no the entire file ??

Tags: awk, gsub

Below is my awk code to sort and split input files and rename it to new output files. But I have a problem as I don't want to keep " " in the filename but my filename for output files are created based on first four columns of input files. file= path ""$1""$2"*"$3"*"$4"_03042017.csv". I have been trying to use gsub to remove " " but it will also remove " " inside files which are not my desire outcome. I just want to remove " " in filename only. Anyone can please help me? Appreciate it a lot.

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN { OFS = "|" } NR==1 {
  for( i=1;i<5;i++) $i = ""
  h = substr($0, index($0,$5)); sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"", h)
  next
  } 

  {
  file= path ""$1""$2"_"$3"_"$4"_03042017.csv"

  # remove 4 first field
  for( i=1;i<5;i++) $i = ""
  # cleaning starting space
  Cleaned = substr($0, index($0,$5)); sub( /^[[:blank:]]+/, "", Cleaned)

  print ( a[file]++ ? "" : "DM9 03042017" ORS h ORS ) Cleaned > file
  }

END {
  for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file
  } ' file1
```

Comment: where did you define "path"?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.